# How to get file names of files in working directory with more than 30 characters in file name written into a text file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

The batch file code used by me:

```
for /r %%f in (*) do (
    echo %%~nf >>testy.txt
)
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (testy.txt) do (
    set _temp=%%a
    for /f "tokens=30*" %%g in (_temp) do (
        echo large=%%g>>length.txt
    )
)
```

It should create `length.txt` having characters at 30th place and above, but it is failing in the 3rd `for` loop which should create `length.txt`.

Comment: Do I understand right that the file length.txt should only contain the file name part exceeding 30 chars? With path and extension or only tha base name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your directory has standard filenames with extensions, you could probably use something far more simple:

```bat
@Where .:"??????????????????????????????*.*">"length.txt"
```

*This should output all files in the current directory containing 30 or more characters in their filenames, (ignoring the extension).*

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with following batch file on no file name of a non-hidden file contains an exclamation mark.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

(for %%I in (*) do (
    set "FileName=%%~nI"
    if not defined FileName set "FileName=%%~xI"
    if not "!FileName:~30!" == "" echo %%~nxI
))>length.txt

rem Delete length.txt if being an empty file.
for %%I in (length.txt) do if %%~zI == 0 del length.txt
endlocal
```

The next batch file is slower, but processes correct also non-hidden files with a `!` in file name.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

(for %%I in (*) do (
    set "FileName=%%~nI"
    if not defined FileName set "FileName=%%~xI"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    if not "!FileName:~30!" == "" echo %%~nxI
    endlocal
))>length.txt

rem Delete length.txt if being an empty file.
for %%I in (length.txt) do if %%~zI == 0 del length.txt
endlocal
```

Both batch files handle the name of a file like `.htaccess` as file with file name being `.htaccess` and having no file extension while Windows command processor handles such files as file name being empty and file extension is `.htaccess`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Comment: @Praneeth: Of course. [I suggested you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53287424/file-name-length#comment93459347_53287424) this method in your previous question... [Twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53287424/file-name-length#comment93504387_53287424)!

Answer (score 1):

Some things are much easier done in PowerShell

To be on topic wrapped in a batch file

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\11\19\SO_53379317.cmd
Echo off
Set Len=30
For /f "delims=" %%A in ('
  powershell -NoP -C "(Get-ChildItem '%CD%' -File| Where-Object {$_.Name.Length -gt %Len%}).Name.SubString(%Len%)"
') Do Echo %%A
```

In case you want the length of drive, path, name and extension replace `.Name` with `.FullName`
The file name without extansion would be `.BaseName`

THe `-File` parameter requires PSv3+ (present in Windows 8+)